Can simulation hypothesis be cracked by the problem of evil?
We all know that Nick Bostrom's cliche argument in favor of Simulation Hypothesis.
My question is very simple and I am wondering if it can crack the Bostrom's hypothesis.
Lets assume that we are living in a simulation and our post human ancestor civilization created the codes of us in this simulation.
I am wondering;
A- What can be the reason of simulating Hitler, serial killers and all other crimes and wars?
B- Why such an advanced civilization will bother by simulation with such blood and pain? Are they enjoying the evil acts in their simulation by watching us suffering?
C- Should not they simulate a better world just even because they are advanced?
I appreciate your answers and thoughts
Note: While searching I found this essay related to the subject for whom are interested in extended source:
Theodicy and the simulation hypothesis, or: The problem of simulator evil
https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/PbfFFs6koYqueaH8o/theodicy-and-the-simulation-hypothesis-or-the-problem-of

In the movie The Matrix, it said that humans could not accept a perfect world. Maybe there's some truth to that? We could stimulate it and find out. I can't even imagine what a perfect world would look like.

@ScottRowe Can you simulate to torture your own  kind? And watch them to suffer by knowing that they are consious.

i think your question has big potential. It can be changed to: why god makes the world whole of lie with the bit of truth only? Or some kind of this.

And what is the reason for the advanced civilization like ours to produce videogames like Dead Space and Manhunt, or movies like Purge? Or, for that matter, real life slaughters like China's cultural revolution, Cambodia's Khmer Rouge or Rwanda's genocide? Advanced civilizations can hardly be expected to act as benevolent gods, and even if they mostly were their deviants will have access to their technology and do with it as they please.

A lot of simulation hypothesis stuff just retreads the arguments about theism. So it feels like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil is relevant here, with the added loosening that we don't have to argue that the simulation-runners are omnibenevolent (or omniscient)

Have you heard of the Milgram experiment?

Well that's an argument against a benevolent God too, right? Why is there evil? Ancient philosophical question.

@Conifold because our civilization is aware that game characters are not concious living beings.

No, your argument doesn't materially affect the plausibility of the simulation hypothesis, since the plausibility is already infinitesimally close to zero without it. A few points you might like to consider:

Why do you suppose whoever, or whatever, is responsible for the simulation has the same aversion to evil that we have?
Why do you suppose they are 'simulating Hitler'? Perhaps they are just simulating DNA, and it just so happens that the simulated DNA evolved to produce Hitler.
Why do you suppose those responsible for the simulation evolved from humans? How do you know humans are not wiped out in the coming millennia and supplanted by a species of hyper intelligent cockroaches?
Why do you suppose those responsible for the simulation are aware of what's going on here and now? They might have thousands of separate simulations running- of which our Universe is just one- and perhaps they peek at them only once every few million years.
Why do you suppose those who launched the simulations are still alive. Perhaps they died after they set the simulation running?
How do you know that the simulators know we are conscious? Perhaps they think we are zombies.
How do you know that the focus of interest of the simulators isn't some advanced empire on the other side of the Universe, and we are just a neglected side effect of the program?

Etc etc etc


Because the hypothesis argues that they are our ancestors. High probability that they have similar aversions.



What ever they do they are letting evil power to act in the world regardless of the method.



My argument is related with Bostrom's hypothessis assuming that they are only post human advanced ancestors



What if not?



In this case we are close to find an error in their simulation because of the lack of upgrades.



I don't think such advanced post human civilization is unaware of what we are exactly.



Where is the other side of the universe?



@Marco Ocram Sorry but your answers are not more than bunch of  maybe rolls sounds like a sci - fi scenario rather than bostrom's hypothesis


@wiseman, but that's my point- you are making lots of unstated assumptions in your questions. Why do you say there is a high -probability they have similar aversions, for example. We used to not have aversions to slavery, homophobia, massacring people for religious reasons etc. How do you have the first idea what aversions post-humans might have?

Likewise Bostrom's initial thesis.

Attacking a vague speculation utterly unsupported by evidence with another vague speculation utterly supported by evidence is pointless. You can conjecture anything you like- it is meaningless. .

I got ÿour point. Thank you

All scientists and researchers would agree that it is better to go through edge cases by simulation than to let them happen in real life:

crash tests for cars
stress tests for laptops
the number of nuclear tests conducted is much larger than the number used in real-life scenarios
...you name it

Would you simulate a perfect world for lab rats? From what I've heard, lab rats are used in completely opposite scenarios.

What is the difference between those who make these simulations and hackers who constantly uses FTA? Total waste of time for their intelligence level.  This is evil, and they seek psychological superiority by applying it in a more uncontrolled way.

good and evil are human made terms, which are bound to morality, which is bound to society.

All your test examples are done for the benefit of humans. In terms of rats they are  at least other species. What is the reason  for simulating Hitler for the benefit of your own kind? @FedorOmni

@FedorOmni They also knew a lot of things, but they were saying things like this.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
